# Docker variables from `env_file` in container build stage

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I want to use variables in my Docker build stage to emplace secrets in a configuration file within the image. The variables are in `docker-variables.env`.

`./service/Dockerfile`

```
FROM python:3.10-slim

WORKDIR /service

# Copy configuration, emplace secrets
COPY ./service/settings.conf /service/settings.conf
RUN eval "echo \"$(cat /service/settings.conf\"" > /service/settings.conf

# ...
```

`./service/settings.conf`

```ini
[settings]
url = http://${HOST}:${PORT}/
```

`./docker-compose.yaml`

```yaml
version: "3.9"
services:

  service:
    build: ./service/
    env_file: ./docker-variables.env
```

`./docker-variables.env`

```
HOST=0.0.0.0
PORT=6800
```

Comment: You either have to set ENV or ARG in docker image, and in docker run you can pass your .env file. But for build, I'm not sure you can pass it, you probably need to rely on ARGs

Comment: Remember, anyone who has a copy of your image can `docker run --rm your-image cat /service/settings.conf` and trivially get those credentials out.  You almost certainly do _not_ want to build them into your image.  `ENV` and `ARG` aren't especially better.

Comment: @DavidMaze I had not realized this; thanks for the heads up. I'll load them at runtime